# How to solve a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How would you solve this differential equation?

I have been trying to use the technique of separable equations, but haven't got very far.

$$\frac{D'(x)}{D(x)}=\frac{x}{1-x}$$

Comment: $\ln(D(x))=\int \frac{x}{1-x} dx$; you are left to compute this integral, which is not that hard. (Start by long dividing.)

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$\frac{x}{1-x} = -\frac{x}{x-1} = - \frac{(x-1) + 1}{x-1} = -1 -\frac{1}{x-1} $$

The integration becomes quite easy. The result may also be obtained by long division as Ian has pointed out in the comments.

Integrating both sides, we get $$\ln(D(x)) = - \int \left(1 +\frac{1}{x-1} \right) \, \text{d}x$$

Can you solve from here?